# Can you do Radios & Other Amounts for Contributions using D9 Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: webform-civicrm

When total amount is added to a Webform CiviCRM it comes in default as type = CiviCRM Number. How do I make this into a Radios & Other Amounts field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Build tab:

- Edit the Element
- Change CiviCRM Number -> CiviCRM Options
- Add some Options
- Save

That will give you Radio buttons - if you want to add an Other Amount option ->

From the Build tab:

- Edit the Element
- Change CiviCRM Options -> Radios other
- Save

To ensure your Other Amount appears underneath the Radios -> add this ->
From the Settings tab -> select CSS/JS
copy this into the Javascript box ->

```
jQuery('.js-webform-radios-other-input').insertAfter(jQuery('#edit-civicrm-1-contribution-1-contribution-total-amount-radios'));
```

Save

End result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks Karin

Comment: Is the Drupal Select Other module also needed to do this?

Comment: No - radios other is native Webform in D9